# Find security and distribution groups with owners whose account is disabled

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for some guidance on creating a powershell script that will check security and distribution groups from specific OU's and see if the owner is a user who's disabled.

We have lots of old groups in our AD created by ex employees that need to be cleaned up.

This is what i've started with.

```
$managedByGroups = get-adgroup -filter 'groupCategory -eq "Distribution"' -SearchBase "OU=SydExchangeGroups,OU=SydGroups,OU=Sydney,DC=my,DC=org,DC=biz" -Properties distinguishedname, managedby | select sAMAccountName, managedby

$disabledUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -SearchBase "OU=SydDisabledUsers,OU=SydMisc,OU=Sydney,DC=my,DC=org,DC=biz" | select distinguishedname

foreach ($group in $managedByGroups){

    if($managedByGroups.managedby -eq $disabledUsers.distinguishedname)
    {
        write-output
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  You're more likely to get help if you show some effort.

Comment: Thanks, i've added to the opening post

Comment: I'm also trying something like this: ```$disabledusers = Get-ADUser  -Filter {Enabled -eq $false}  -Searchbase 'OU=SydDisabledUsers,OU=SydMisc,OU=Sydney,DC=my,DC=org,DC=biz'
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup
$groups | where-object { ( Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | where-object { $_.ManagedBy -eq $disabledusers}) } ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out eventually by doing the following:

```
$myDisabledUsers = @()
$date = get-date -format dd-MM-yyyy
$managedSydGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * -Searchbase "OU=SydExchangeGroups,OU=SydGroups,OU=Sydney,DC=my,DC=biz,DC=org" | where {$_.managedby -ne $null} | select name, managedby
$disabledSydUser = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=SydDisabledUsers,OU=SydMisc,OU=Sydney,DC=my,DC=biz,DC=org" | where {$_.enabled -eq $false} | select -ExpandProperty distinguishedname

$disabledOwners = foreach($group in $managedSydGroups)
{
    $managedByString = [string]$group.managedby
    if($disabledSydUser -contains $managedByString)
    {$myDisabledUsers += $group} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your if block:

- you are looping through $managedByGroups, but you are never using that variable (it should be $group.managedby)
- you are trying to compare 1 element with a list of elements, in this case consider using -in operator instead of -eq.
- you should treat the case when there is no value for managedby attribute, in case you do not get the desired results.

An alternative to your code may is below.
I'm first getting the list of managedby users, then i'm looping though each entry, and if it is not null, we try to do a get-aduser filtering by enabled status and the distinguishedname.

$DisabledManagedBy variable will contains ADUser objects which are disabled.

```
$grp = get-adgroup -filter 'groupCategory -eq "Distribution"' -Properties ManagedBy,DistinguishedName


$DisabledManagedBy = foreach ($item in $grp.ManagedBy) {
    if ($item) {
        Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false -and DistinguishedName -like $item} -Properties DistinguishedName
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, this script ends without returning anything?

Comment: Okay if I pipe it with $DisabledManagedBy | write-output then it comes up. The thing is, it's showing me the users who are disabled and are owners of a group.. but not which group. Any way to do that?

Comment: One way to make a report of group names for which disabled managers exist is this one. $Report = @()
$grp = get-adgroup -filter 'groupCategory -eq "Distribution"' -Properties ManagedBy,DistinguishedName

foreach ($item in $grp) {
    if ($item) {
        $row = "" | Select-Object Group,DisMgr
        $ManagedBy = $item.ManagedBy
        $disuser = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false -and DistinguishedName -like $ManagedBy} -Properties DistinguishedName
        $row.Group = $grp.UserPrincipalName
        $row.DisMgr= $disuser.UserPrincipalName
        $Report += $row
        }   }